# Following RoR3 tutorial- tests are inconsistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial, chapter 6. Inside my directory `spec/models/user_spec.rb`, i have a 6 test cases (no need to rly read them):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  #pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com"}
  end

  it "should creat a new instance given valid attributes" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end

  .
  .
  .

  it "should reject invalid email addresses" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
    addresses.each do |address|
      invalid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
      invalid_email_user.should_not be_valid
    end
  end

end
```

In the console, i type `$ rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb` and it spits out

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
*

Pending:
  User add some examples to (or delete) /Users/matthew/Desktop/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb
    # Not Yet Implemented
    # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4

Finished in 0.00023 seconds
1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

The last line says i only have 1 example and 1 pending, but i've written 6 tests! This inconsistency boggles my mind! No syntax errors, i'm saving the file, i'm in the right directory, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the strangest thing (i'm using Mac OS X and Textmate):

Despite correct code, directory, etc. CMD+S or File-> Save was not saving the files at all. I've been opening the files via command line. Solution is to just close the shell and open a new one.